# delegate returns nil tvOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out from long time. Can someone tell me why my delegate method is never called. Its a tvOS project but i believe it should work as simple iOS app. On click of button i have a popup table view and on select i am trying to update button label with selected option.

```
protocol PopupSelectionHandlerProtocol{
    func UpdateSelected(data:String)
}

class PopupViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    let months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
    let days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
    let yearsRange = [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020]
    var popupType:String!
    var delegate:PopupSelectionHandlerProtocol?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        popupType = "months"
    }


    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (popupType == "months"){
            return 12
        }else if (popupType == "days"){
            return 31
        }else if (popupType == "years")
        {
            return 6
        }
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(months[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)
        delegate?.UpdateSelected((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!)
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

And then This -

```
class VacationPlannerController: UIViewController,PopupSelectionHandlerProtocol {

    @IBOutlet weak var fromMonth: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let popupDelegate = PopupViewController()
        popupDelegate.delegate = self
    }

    func UpdateSelected(data:String){
        print("Inside UpdateSelected VacationPlannerController \(data)")
        fromMonth.titleLabel?.text = data
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate in storyboard by Ctrl+Drag or rightClick hold + drag from the tableView to the ViewController?

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: which delegate method is not getting a call, updateSelected or tableView's delegate methods?

Comment: updateSelected is not getting called ... i am getting the popup table view with data loaded but on select of any row i am trying to call updateSelected delegate method which is not working

Comment: are you getting a call to didSelectRowAtIndexpath: ?

Comment: yes didSelectRowAtIndexpath is getting called

Comment: `let popupDelegate = PopupViewController()` This won't use the storyboard

Comment: i tried this but did not work -
        let popController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("popup") as! PopupViewController
        popController.delegate = self

Comment: @RichaSrivastava is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes its resolved thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to resolve this issue -

First in PopupViewController- 
In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, replaced

```
delegate?.UpdateSelected((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!)
```

with

```
self.delegate?.UpdateSelected((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!)
```

And Second in VacationPlannerController- 
Removed below code from viewDidLoad -

```
    let popupDelegate = PopupViewController()
    popupDelegate.delegate = self
```

And added prepareForSegue -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PopupViewController
        destinationVC.delegate = self
    }
```

And issue resolved yeeee :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, you are getting your delegate as nil, since there can be only one ViewController at a time presented. Since your popupViewController's view is not loaded. The viewDidLoad() method is not getting called, resulting in non-setting of popupDelegate.

If you want to check its nullity. Try this in your didSelect... Method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VacationPlannerController(), animated: true)
    if(delegate==nil){
        print("delegate is nil")
    }
    delegate?.UpdateSelected((tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.textLabel?.text)!)
}
```

If you want the fromMonth button to be updated. First you will need to present/push VacationPlannerController in order to call its viewDidLoad(). Then only you will be able to update its property, that is, fromMonth label.

Comment: popupViewController's is a popup which i had dismissed no need to navigate to VacationPlannerController. I just added prepareForSegue in vacationplanner and it worked!

Comment: @RichaSrivastava Ohk good,thats what uh required! But can you please upvote the answer if it helped you to find the problem, so that others too can understand the problem, though the solution that you need is presented by you.